# Packery JS with a predefined grid

Tags: javascript, html, packery

So i am making a website that has a tiled page with different size tiles on it. I have wrote javaScript that takes tiles, number of columns and number of rows. It then creates a grid and fits tiles perfectly in the grid and fills up any spare spaces with small one block tiles. what i get a the end is an array of tiles there size and there cooridantes based on the amount of columns and rows eg,

```
        blocks = [
        {
            element: $('<div class="large"></div>'),
            width: 3,
            height: 2,
            yPos: 0,
            xPos: 0
        },
        {
            element: $('<div class="medium"></div>'),
            width: 2,
            height: 2,
            yPos: 0,
            xPos: 3
        },
        {
            element: $('<div class="small"></div>'),
            width: 1,
            height: 1,
            yPos: 0,
            xPos: 6
        },
        {
            element: $('<div class="small"></div>'),
            width: 1,
            height: 1,
            yPos: 2,
            xPos: 0
        }
    ]
```

the actual array has more in it and will make a perfect grid with no white space and straight along the bottom.

I now need to print this to the screen somehow. I at first used a table and by using the number of rows and columns attributes i could create a perfect grid with the sizes i needed. the only problem is I would like it to be responsive and change the number of columns based on screen size. I really like how packery does this. I thought i could use pkery.fit() to achieve what i wanted by setting coordinates and passing it an element but it doesn't seem to work that way. does anyone now if i can do what Im trying to achieve with Packery? I am also using percentage size to make it more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I figured out a solution I take my array of tile objects and i order them by there coordinates giving Y precedence:

```
    function organizeByPosition(){
    addedBlocks.sort(function sortByPosition(a, b){
        if (a.positionY == b.positionY) return a.positionX - b.positionX;
            return a.positionY - b.positionY;
        })
    }
```

Now all i have to do is use packery to append these items in this order and packery seems to layout as intended:

```
    var elements = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
        if(blocks[i].getWidth() == 3){
            elements.push($('<div class="grid-item grid-item--width3"></div>').append('<div class="content"></div>'));
        }
        if(blocks[i].getWidth() == 2){
            elements.push($('<div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>').append('<div class="content"></div>'));
        }
        if(blocks[i].getWidth() == 1){
            elements.push($('<div class="grid-item"></div>').append('<div class="content"></div>'));
        }
    }

    var displayGrid = $('.grid');
    displayGrid.packery( args2 );
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        displayGrid.append(elements[i]).packery('appended', elements[i]);
    }
```

it appears i was overthinking packery when i wanted to fit to certain coordinates. At least my code didn't go to waste as its a perfect way to get the order to append the elements to get a perfect grid with no spaces thats a perfect rectangle/square. Also as the code i wrote generates a random grid I get the tiles in a different order on every refresh which is was what i was going for